# Angular, build error model

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm trying to build the Angular app I'm working on but recently It does not work. 
I was working on model folder, there are just typescript classes **inside the src folder**

The error: Module build failed: Error: **C:\Users\USER\PhpstormProjects\holidaywatch\src\app\model\country.model.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.**

Everything is included in the src folder (there is no app content out of this folder). I read that angular compiles everything inside the src folder and there is no need to add path in some tsconfig.

Did someone face the same problem as I did? I didnt change much. I just added one class to model folder and project didnt build.

Comment: Double check all of your imports to make sure they are using the correct path, and the casing in the class names are correct.

Comment: Well. I found the file. When I delete imports (and methods using these imports) its fine. But I cant see the problem. For example *import {HotelModel} from '../model/hotel.model';*. The file from where I import is on the same level as the model. The classname is HotelModel.

Comment: The file you are adding the `import` to, what folder is it in in relation to the *src\model* folder?

Comment: Its service. So its src/services/... . The model folder is src/model. So its ../ (one level up from the services, then model then find the proper model. Even my IDE has no problem with that. I have no clue why angular does not compile it.

Comment: Seems correct. If you happen to be running `ng serve` while coding these classes and started getting the error, stop and restart it; perhaps the error will clear. Sometimes `ng serve` gets funny about new classes being added to an application in my experience.

Comment: I tried to close terminal, restart PC. Still not working. Where and how I can add the model folder to get rid of this error? There are multiple tsconfigs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Well. I kinda solved it.
I reinstalled whole node.js, deleted node_modules and redownloaded it.

After this, the angular had no more problems with this. I really dont know what caused this, but If you face this, this is possible "solution".